# On Role-playing True-to-Canon Elves Despite Fellow Players Promoting Orcs

Tags: dnd-3.5e, roleplaying, group-dynamics

While I have read all the 3.5 sourcebooks -- and had some practically memorised, I haven't played that many campaigns.  One of the few that I did, I went with a Lawful Neutral Grey Elf Wizard, and as part of my backstory wanted my character to be very conservative and traditional, and entrenched in his beliefs, steeped in that which was important to Elven culture, most specifically including the Elven hatred, loathing, contempt, and desire to utterly expunge the Orcs.  I felt it meshed well with the rest of my backstory, with our campaign setting, and with the campaign details I was given.  However, unbeknownst to me, another player chose to be a half-Orc.  This would have been problematic were it not for the fact that his love of leaping into combat got him killed right off the bat, but his replacement character, a human Paladin, chose to make it his mission to proselyte to and convert the Orcs into law-abiding beings, while one of my long-term goals was to eventually cleanse the Material Plane of every last drop of Orc blood.  I chose to roleplay this and take the conflicting dynamic as an opportunity for immersion, but my fellow players grew rather frustrated by my character's unwillingness to give up his heritage for another's whims, and the scenario collapsed before any solution arose.
I am not trying to argue that Orcs shouldn't be considered capable of alignment shift or civilised behaviour, or that my character's actions were Good (his moral component of alignment was Neutral), but how does one reconcile character motivations that conflict in a manner where for one to succeed the other must fail?  Do we go by precedence, allowing the Elf's mission to succeed because he was around longer?  Do we choose by dragging modern era moral systems into feudal societies and ban canon racial hatred as racist, despite how very pertinent such attitudes and behaviours were in those societies, thus removing part of that aspect of realism that makes the game so well-beloved?

Edit: After reading @HeyICanChan 's response, I read up on MyGuy, and can recognise that this was indeed both my reaction and the other player's.  I personally enjoyed the added dynamic, but he didn't, so once the DM arranged a near-TPK with his unbalanced homebrewed monster, he didn't return.  However, the reason he chose to champion that cause was because he personally disliked my incorporating canonic racial hatred and the gravity that comes with that sort of belief into my character, so the question I meant to ask is how do you reconcile the desire for serious acknowledgement of and revelry in the darkness of feudalism with players who want a much lighter tone when those desires are mutually exclusive?

Comment: This seems very opinion based - there's no "best answer" to how you should deal with these situations, it depends entirely on the people you're playing with. As such, there's a good chance this question will be closed. Still, welcome to the site. I hope it doesn't deter you from  asking more in the future :)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. I suspect someone will edit this so it's not quite so wall-of-text-y; that's okay—that happens around these parts. I suggest you read up on My Guy Syndrome [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37103/8610) then revisit this question. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Agreed with @erik -- almost everyone who reads this will have a way they would handle it, but it all comes down to giving you advice on how to play your characters.  That's something we just don't do, because it is inherently an opinion.  No one can play your character but you.

Comment: RE: "[H]ow do you reconcile the desire for serious acknowledgement of and revelry in the darkness of feudalism with players who want a much lighter tone when those desires are mutually exclusive?" Consider, then, also looking at [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/92290/8610) on the Same-page Tool, then perhaps revisiting this question again afterward?

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105388/what-is-a-session-0

Comment: @Philipp [Please don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/52137).

Comment: I don't think it's opinion-based at all.  Indeed, the basic answers to the questions the OP is asking have been given in comments (in abbreviated form) in the form of three "related question" links.  Voting to reopen.